# PHP ZendFramework zf command not found

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework

Hy,

I've installed Zend Server on my OSX 10.9.3 recently. I've gone trough a lot of manual, copied the zf.sh and zf.php beside the php binary (/usr/bin) and copied the ZendFramework/libary content to the PHP include folder. After this, I'm can't use the zf command in terminal.

Also with this command it wont't work.

```
alias zf=/usr/bin/zf.sh
```

If I try to run "zf" after this I got the following message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/zf.sh: Permission denied
```

If I use "sudo zf" I got this:

```
sudo: zf: command not found
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alias, and don't forget to reinitialize bash after adding new alias.

```
 alias zf='sudo bash /usr/bin/zf.sh'
```